# Split string by carriage return line feed

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to split a string by char 10 and 13. In all these cases below the entire string with `\r` and `\n` ends up in first element lines(0) What am I doing wrong?

Code is running on Windows 10. VB.NET:

```
Dim info As String = "abc\rsome data \nmore data\n the end\r"

Dim lines As String() = info.Split(New Char() {Chr(13), Chr(10)})
lines = info.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
lines = info.Replace(Chr(13), "").Split(Chr(10))
lines = info.Split(New Char() {vbCrLf, vbCr, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
lines = info.Split(New Char() {"\r", "\n", "\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that `vbCrLf` is a string of two characters, not a single character, so it won't fit in a `Char()`. (Also, `vbCr` and `vbLf` are strings of length 1.) If you set [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects) then Visual Studio can point out problems like that for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VB.Net doesn't support escape characters like C# does, so your `"\n"` is literally the two characters `"\"` and `"n"`.

To build that string in the first place, you should use the `Chr` function. Here it is using string interpolation

```vb
Dim info = $"abc{Chr(13)}some data {Chr(10)}more data{Chr(10)} the end{Chr(13)}"
```

Now your code should work

```vb
Dim lines = info.Split({Chr(10), Chr(13)})
```

Your original string is not equivalent to

```vb
Dim info = "abc
some data 
more data
the end
"
```

since:

`Chr(13) <> Environment.NewLine`

`Chr(10) <> Environment.NewLine`

In Windows, `Environment.NewLine = Chr(13) & Chr(10)`

Comment: Thanks. Yes orginal feed was coming from a scanner (string posted sanitized here) and was working fine in a c# context, even used in Tests! Problem is I tried to use that string verbatim in a vb.net program. Hence the errors. Like you pointed out \n is two chars in vb.net :) Baffled as to why I was downvoted. This is useful info imho!

Answer (score 2):

Line breaks can be carriage returns, line feeds or a carriage return and a line feed together. The pair is obviously the default for Windows but the carriage return alone is the default for Unix and is used by the Windows WordPad app, presumably for RTF interoperability with Unix. In VB.NET, you should use the `ControlChars` class for this sort of thing. The `Cr` field is a `Char` containing a carriage return, the `Lf` field is a `Char` containing a line feed and both the `CrLf` and `NewLine` fields are `Strings` containing both a carriage return and a line feed. If you want to split on a carriage return and line feed pair then you need to use one of the overloads of `String.Split` that splits on substrings and not single `Chars`, e.g.

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim str = "First line
Second line
Third line"
        Dim parts = str.Split({ControlChars.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)

        For i = 0 To parts.GetUpperBound(0)
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} {parts(i)}")
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

Output:

```
0 First line
1 Second line
2 Third line
```

If you want to allow single-character line breaks too then you can specify multiple delimiters. Just be sure to put the multi-character options first, so they take precedence, e.g.

```vb
Dim str = $"First line{ControlChars.Cr}Second line{ControlChars.Lf}Third line{ControlChars.CrLf}Fourth line"
Dim parts = str.Split({ControlChars.NewLine, ControlChars.Cr, ControlChars.Lf}, StringSplitOptions.None)

For i = 0 To parts.GetUpperBound(0)
    Console.WriteLine($"{i} {parts(i)}")
Next
```